# Is Sending User Credentials through HTTP Headers is a secured way of Communication with outside server

Tags: java, servlets

Hi I am trying to send User Credentials from header to a third party application. Is this a secure way of sending the credentials.

Comment: It's only secure if you're using HTTPS. If you _are_ using HTTPS, any method is secure.

Comment: Maybe?  Definitely depends on your threat profile, permission model, user model, architecture, business requirements, etc...  Have you consider OAuth or similar?

Comment: To put it more simply, secure from what?

Comment: @Taylor: I mean secure from an intruder attack over the Network who can theft user credentials. I haven't used any of the models you have mentioned above. I am using HTTPS to redirect to the Server

Comment: Then  as @MikeW said earlier only if you're using https